# Getting <generator object inner at 0x7f2ad7874050> error Flask

Tags: python, flask

Getting this error `<generator object inner at 0x7f2ad7874050>` on my page when I try to run the folliwhing flask function (route):

```
@app.route('/siteON', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def siteon():
    def inner():
        proc = subprocess.Popen(
            ['/root/site_toggle/flaskr/testON.sh'],
            shell=True,
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE
        )
        for line in iter(proc.stdout.readline,''):
            time.sleep(1) 
            yield line.rstrip() + '<br/>\n'
    output = inner ()
    return render_template('layout.html', ON_output=output)
```

here is my html

```
<input type="button" name="lien2" value="Turn OFF site"
 onclick="self.location.href='http://10.10.10.30:5000/siteOFF'" style="background-color:#1ab171"
style="color:white; font-weight:bold"onclick>
<p>{{ ON_output }}</p>
```

I am looking to run button and display the output on the same flask page without streaming the output on a new page.
Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: You can at least display all the values printed by the script, something like `output = '<br/>'.join(inner())`, but as Amber noted you won't make them update in realtime this easily.

Comment: Thanks  !!! adding '<br/>'.join(inner()) almost worked for me just having the br/ not recognize and getting displayed on every line. Is there a way to prevent that ?

Comment: Not sure, this is something to lurk for in Flask mans, how can one add more nodes to the DOM inside a Python code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not an error, that's the string representation of a generator object, which is what `yield` results in your function creating.

You seem to be trying to use a generator and `sleep()` to make things appear over time in your page, but that's not how templates work - they're a one-and-done kind of rendering. If you want things to appear over time in your page you're probably going to have to use some form of client-side javascript to fetch new updates.